# Postfix unable to pass messages to amavis ( Can't connect to INET4 socket 127.0.0.1)

Tags: postfix

I have been trying to get postfix to work with amavis but have been unable.  No matter what I have tried I can't get past the following error:  `[snip] Can't connect to INET4 socket 127.0.0.1`

I can successfully run telnet 127.0.0.1 10024 and amavis answers.

Nothing else in the logs to indicate a problem.

Does anyone know how I can further troubleshoot this?

`postconf -n` follows:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = thegodshalls.com, localhost.com, , localhost
myhostname = thegodshalls.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =       permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

Comment: not enough information, anyway using this how-to http://www.howtoforge.com/amavisd_postfix_debian_ubuntu

Comment: can you post the output of `postconf -n` and the complete log lines generated by postfix to help you better.

Comment: Thanks to both for even looking.  I have posted the postconf -n.  I originally followed this page for installing and configuring. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixAmavisNew

Answer (score 1):

Amavisd mailing list gave me a pointer not listed on previous searches which was to try and `telnet` to port `10025`.  I was unable to connect to port `10025`.  But `lsof -i tcp:10025` showed that postfix was listening.

I added a rule to `iptables` to allow port `10025` and now it works.